# nodelets problem

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, nodelets

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I'm trying to create a custom pgk with nodelets.
I read already manual http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet/Tutorials/Porting%20nodes%20to%20nodelets
And for more understanding I use the pkg: https://github.com/tysik/obstacle_detector
And I got error

```
[ERROR] [1569303210.735895568]:Loader::load Failed to load nodelet [/test_nodelet1] of type [safety_zones/TestNodelet1] even after refreshing the cache: MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create object of class type safety_zones::TestNodelet1Nodelet as no factory exists for it. Make sure that the library exists and was explicitly loaded through MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()
[ERROR] [1569303210.735951283]:Loader::load The error before refreshing the cache was: MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create object of class type safety_zones::TestNodelet1Nodelet as no factory exists for it. Make sure that the library exists and was explicitly loaded through MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()
```

Any help, please. Thank you!

CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(safety_zones)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  roslaunch
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  std_srvs
  pluginlib
  nodelet
)


###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if your package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES test_nodelet1 test_nodelet2 ${PROJECT_NAME}_nodelets
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
    roscpp
    roslaunch
    sensor_msgs
    std_msgs
    std_srvs
    pluginlib
    nodelet
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
 include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a C++ library

add_library(test_nodelet1 src/test_nodelet1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_nodelet1 ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(test_nodelet1 ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

add_library(test_nodelet2 src/test_nodelet2.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_nodelet2 ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(test_nodelet2 ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

#
# Build nodes
#

add_executable(test_nodelet1_node src/nodes/test_nodelet1_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_nodelet1_node test_nodelet1)

add_executable(test_nodelet2_node src/nodes/test_nodelet2_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_nodelet2_node test_nodelet2)

#
# Build nodelets
#
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_nodelets
  src/nodelets/test_nodelet1_nodelet.cpp
  src/nodelets/test_nodelet2_nodelet.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_nodelets test_nodelet1 test_nodelet2)


#
# Install libraries
#
install(TARGETS test_nodelet1 test_nodelet2 ${PROJECT_NAME}_nodelets 
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_BIN_DESTINATION})


#
# Install nodes
#
install(TARGETS test_nodelet1_node test_nodelet2_node
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})


#
# Install header files
#
install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION})


#
# Install nodelet #and rviz plugins description
#
install(FILES nodelet_plugins.xml
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
```

package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>safety_zones</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The safety_zones package</description>

  <!-- One maintainer tag required, multiple allowed, one person per tag -->
  <!-- Example:  -->
  <!-- <maintainer email="jane.doe@example.com">Jane Doe</maintainer> -->
  <maintainer email=""></maintainer>

  <license>TODO</license>
   <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>roslaunch</build_depend>
  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_srvs</build_depend>
  <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>roslaunch</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>sensor_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_srvs</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>roslaunch</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>sensor_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_srvs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>pluginlib</exec_depend>
  <build_depend>pluginlib</build_depend>
  <build_depend>nodelet</build_depend>
  <exec_depend>nodelet</exec_depend>

  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <nodelet plugin="${prefix}/nodelet_plugins.xml" />
  </export>
</package>
```

nodelet_plugins.xml

```
<library path="lib/libsafety_zones">

  <class name="safety_zones/TestNodelet1" 
         type="safety_zones::TestNodelet1Nodelet" 
         base_class_type="nodelet::Nodelet">
    <description>
      TestNodelet1
    </description>
  </class>

  <class name="safety_zones/TestNodelet2" 
         type="safety_zones::TestNodelet2Nodelet" 
         base_class_type="nodelet::Nodelet">
    <description>
      TestNodelet2
    </description>
  </class>
</library>
```

test_nodelet1.h

```
#pragma once
#include <ros/ros.h>

#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>

namespace safety_zones
{
class TestNodelet1
{
public:
  TestNodelet1(ros::NodeHandle& nh, ros::NodeHandle& nh_local);
  ~TestNodelet1();

private:
  ros::Subscriber scan_sub_;
  ros::Publisher scan_pub_;
  void scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr &msg);
};


} // namespace safety_zones
```

test_nodelet1.cpp

```
#include <safety_zones/test_nodelet1.h>

using namespace safety_zones;

TestNodelet1::TestNodelet1(ros::NodeHandle& nh, ros::NodeHandle& nh_local)
{
  ROS_INFO_STREAM("init TestNodelet1");
  scan_sub_ = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("/scan_back", 1, &TestNodelet1::scanCallback, this);
  scan_pub_ = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("/scan_test", 1);
}
TestNodelet1::~TestNodelet1()
{
}

void TestNodelet1::scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr &msg)
{
  ROS_INFO_STREAM("first_callback");
  scan_pub_.publish(msg);
}
```

test_nodelet1_nodelet.cpp

```
#include <memory>
#include <nodelet/nodelet.h>

#include "safety_zones/test_nodelet1.h"

namespace safety_zones
{

class TestNodelet1Nodelet : public nodelet::Nodelet
{
public:
  virtual void onInit()
  {
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("111");
    ros::NodeHandle nh = getNodeHandle();
    ros::NodeHandle nh_local = getPrivateNodeHandle();

    try
    {
      NODELET_INFO("[TestNodelet1]: Initializing nodelet");
      test_nodelet1_ = std::shared_ptr<TestNodelet1>(new TestNodelet1(nh, nh_local));
    }
    catch (const char *s)
    {
      NODELET_FATAL_STREAM("[TestNodelet1]: " << s);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
      NODELET_FATAL_STREAM("[TestNodelet1]: Unexpected error");
    }
  }

  // virtual ~TestNodelet1Nodelet()
  // {
  //   NODELET_INFO("[TestNodelet1]: Shutdown");
  // }

private:
  std::shared_ptr<TestNodelet1> test_nodelet1_;
};

} // namespace safety_zones

#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(safety_zones::TestNodelet1Nodelet, nodelet::Nodelet)
```

my launch file

```
<!-- Demonstation of obstacle detector -->
<launch>
  <node name="nodelet_manager" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" args="manager" output="screen">
    <param name="num_worker_threads" value="20"/>
  </node>

  <node name="test_nodelet1" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" args="load safety_zones/TestNodelet1 nodelet_manager" output="screen">
  </node>
<!-- 
  <node name="test_nodelet2" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" args="load safety_zones/TestNodelet2 nodelet_manager">
  </node> -->

</launch>
<!-- -->
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333758/nodelets-problem/) by [listenreality](https://answers.ros.org/users/46107/listenreality/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-24**:
I would first check whether things work without forcing C++17 in your own package.

Plugin loading works by being able to introspection and by assuming certain functions/methods exist in your `.so`. But that requires ABI between the host and the library.

ROS Melodic is not compiled with C++17 enabled, so it may be that by forcing it in your nodelet, you're breaking ABI causing the plugin loader unable to load (or: find) your nodelet.

Everything could be fine ABI-wise, but it's easy to check and if it is the cause, prevents us from checking all sorts of other things.

**Comment by [listenreality](https://answers.ros.org/users/46107/listenreality/) on 2019-09-24**:
@gvdhoorn so, I changed it to C++11, and still got the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> 

Are you sure about this ? In your `CMakeList` you declare the library with `add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_nodelets` so you should change `libsafety_zones` for `libsafety_zones_nodelets` or remove the `_nodelets` within the `CMakeList`.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-24**:
Ah, @Delb's comment is probably the answer here.

I would still be careful with forcing C++17 in a package that basically requires ABI compatibility with the host that is going to load it, but not listing the correct library name is going to be an even bigger problem.

**Comment by [listenreality](https://answers.ros.org/users/46107/listenreality/) on 2019-09-24**:
@Delb  Thanks, that helped!